# Accessing an Arrays and Dictionaries with Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, indexing, uicolor

I am trying assemble a UIColor using the following function:

```
var backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()    

let colorsDictionary = chemistryDictionary["backgroundColor"] as! [String: CGFloat]

    backgroundColor = rgbColorFromDictionary(colorsDictionary)
}

func rgbColorFromDictionary(colorDictionary: [String: CGFloat]) -> UIColor {
    let red = colorDictionary["red"]!
    let green = colorDictionary["green"]!
    let blue = colorDictionary["blue"]!
    let alpha = colorDictionary["alpha"]!

    return UIColor(red: red/255.0, green: green/255.0, blue: blue/255.0, alpha: alpha)
}
}
```

I am drawing he color makeup from the following library (using the scale key):

```
struct ColorMatchLibrary {
let library = [

// pH Array
[   "title": "pH",
"description": "Most living things depend on proper pH level to sustain life.",
"scale":
["6.2":
["red": 212, "green": 142, "blue": 69, "alpha": 1.0],

"6.8":
["red": 209, "green": 122, "blue": 31, "alpha": 1.0],

"7.2":
["red": 196, "green": 80, "blue": 9, "alpha": 1.0],

"7.8":
["red": 194, "green": 74, "blue": 58, "alpha": 1.0],

"8.4":
["red": 208, "green": 48, "blue": 75, "alpha": 1.0]
]
],
// Ammonia Array

[   "title": "Ammonia",
"description": "",
"scale":
[
"0":
["red": 244, "green": 235, "blue": 130, "alpha": 1.0],
".25":
["red": 233, "green": 233, "blue": 156, "alpha": 1.0],
".5":
["red": 223, "green": 238, "blue": 141, "alpha": 1.0],
"1.0":
["red": 221, "green": 236, "blue": 210, "alpha": 1.0],
"3.0":
["red": 202, "green": 227, "blue": 191, "alpha": 1.0],
"6.0":
["red": 186, "green": 216, "blue": 173, "alpha": 1.0]
]
]


]
}
```

I am wondering if the function is taking the incorrect parameter or if I have to modify my code to fit the function. I have tried to modify the parameter but I get a ton of errors. So I guess my question is the following:

How would I create a function to accept the scale keys color values or, if that will not work, do I have to change my code overall or the library itself?

Here is all my code:

```
var backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()    

let colorsDictionary = chemistryDictionary["backgroundColor"] as! [String: CGFloat]

    backgroundColor = rgbColorFromDictionary(colorsDictionary)
}

func rgbColorFromDictionary(colorDictionary: [String: CGFloat]) -> UIColor {
    let red = colorDictionary["red"]!
    let green = colorDictionary["green"]!
    let blue = colorDictionary["blue"]!
    let alpha = colorDictionary["alpha"]!

    return UIColor(red: red/255.0, green: green/255.0, blue: blue/255.0, alpha: alpha)
}
}
```

Other file:

```
struct ColorMatchLibrary {
let library = [

// pH Array
[   "title": "pH",
"description": "Most living things depend on proper pH level to sustain life.",
"scale":
["6.2":
["red": 212, "green": 142, "blue": 69, "alpha": 1.0],

"6.8":
["red": 209, "green": 122, "blue": 31, "alpha": 1.0],

"7.2":
["red": 196, "green": 80, "blue": 9, "alpha": 1.0],

"7.8":
["red": 194, "green": 74, "blue": 58, "alpha": 1.0],

"8.4":
["red": 208, "green": 48, "blue": 75, "alpha": 1.0]
]
],
// Ammonia Array

[   "title": "Ammonia",
"description": "",
"scale":
[
"0":
["red": 244, "green": 235, "blue": 130, "alpha": 1.0],
".25":
["red": 233, "green": 233, "blue": 156, "alpha": 1.0],
".5":
["red": 223, "green": 238, "blue": 141, "alpha": 1.0],
"1.0":
["red": 221, "green": 236, "blue": 210, "alpha": 1.0],
"3.0":
["red": 202, "green": 227, "blue": 191, "alpha": 1.0],
"6.0":
["red": 186, "green": 216, "blue": 173, "alpha": 1.0]
]
]
]
}
```

Any suggestions or input is greatly appreciated. Please leave the updated, delete, added, or substituted code in your answer and explain why you did what you did.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

How would I modify the following code to fit the changes?

```
struct Chemistry {

var title: String?
var description: String?
var backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()

init(index: Int) {
    let colorMatchLibrary = ColorMatchLibrary.library
    let chemistryDictionary = colorMatchLibrary[index]

    title = chemistryDictionary["title"] as! String!
    description = chemistryDictionary["description"] as! String!

    let colorsDictionary = chemistryDictionary["backgroundColor"] as! [String: UIColor]

    backgroundColor = rgbColorFromDictionary(colorsDictionary)
}

func rgbColorFromDictionary(colorDictionary: [String: UIColor]) -> UIColor {
   let red = colorDictionary["red"]!
   let green = colorDictionary["green"]!
   let blue = colorDictionary["blue"]!
   let alpha = colorDictionary["alpha"]!

   return UIColor(red: red/255.0, green: green/255.0, blue: blue/255.0, alpha: alpha)
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing your `ColorMatchLibrary` in this way? Why not break it down into smaller structs that are easier to access? Also, why not store the `UIColor` objects directly instead of storing the component values and creating them every time you use them?

Comment: I understand what you mean by break down the Library but what do you mean by store the UIColors directly? Also, if I have 2 different sections of colors, could i store them in the same struct or should I split them. If I spit them up, How would I code the Function then?

Comment: Instead of storing a dictionary of color values for each scale you can simply create a dictionary of `[String:UIColor]`, then when you look up the scale you'll get the color directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this type of organization:

```
struct ColorMatchInfo {
  let title:String
  let description:String
  let scaleColors:[String:UIColor]
}

extension UIColor {
  convenience init(red:Int, green:Int, blue:Int) {
    self.init(red: CGFloat(red)/255.0, green: CGFloat(green)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
  }
}

let colorMatches = [
  ColorMatchInfo(title: "ph",
                 description: "Most living things depend on proper pH level to sustain life.",
                 scaleColors: [
                  "6.2": UIColor(red: 212, green: 142, blue: 69),
                  "6.8": UIColor(red: 209, green: 122, blue: 31),
                  "7.2": UIColor(red: 196, green:  80, blue:  9),
                  "7.8": UIColor(red: 194, green:  74, blue: 58),
                  "8.4": UIColor(red: 208, green:  48, blue: 75)
    ]),
  ColorMatchInfo(title: "Ammonia",
                 description: "",
                 scaleColors: [
                  "0.00": UIColor(red: 244, green: 235, blue: 130),
                  "0.25": UIColor(red: 233, green: 233, blue: 156),
                  "0.50": UIColor(red: 223, green: 238, blue: 141),
                  "1.00": UIColor(red: 221, green: 236, blue: 210),
                  "3.00": UIColor(red: 202, green: 227, blue: 191),
                  "6.00": UIColor(red: 202, green: 216, blue: 173)
    ]),
]

let aColor = colorMatches[0].scaleColors["6.2"]
```

Comment: I modified my question. I will accept your answer but how would I modify the  edited in code to fit the code above?

Comment: @Buster You don't have the key "backgroundDictionary" in any of your dictionaries. Would it be a part of the structure under each index of your `ColorMatchLibrary`?

Comment: The background color is the background color for each of the UIButtons I have (6). I don't know if I need that anymore now that I am using [String: UIColor] instead. But, how would I control which button is which color?

Comment: You have this line, `let colorsDictionary = chemistryDictionary["backgroundColor"] as! [String: UIColor]` Where is this key in your dictionaries? Right now that's the only color you are using and yet I can't see where you're getting it from.

Comment: Would backgroundColor be replaced with scale with the new code then?

Comment: The key `"scale"` in your code references a dictionary of type `[String:[Int]]`. On the other hand `"backgroundColor"` is of type `[String: CGFloat]`. How do you want to convert between the types? Which item does it refer to in the array? Not to mention that `"scale"` is contained in another array dictionaries, how do you choose which one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102402/discussion-between-kenneth-bruno-and-buster).